# Visual Studio 2015 wont find all the possible results in a search, only the first one

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am having an issue where Visual Studio will only stick to the first results it finds in my project, particularly in my .min.js file which is very annoying.

For example, if I try to find : documents.push, it stops after it found the results in the .min.js file and will not continue afterwards, any help?

Comment: I would check that the search scope hasn't changed to "Selection".  When the search scope is Selection and the search term is highlighted from being the result of a previous search, the search will seem to be "stuck".  This seems to happen to me from time to time randomly.

Comment: sadly that is not the case (I just double checked) , thanks anyways